# Will ggcorplot() create a correlation matrix for lm() model having two dependent variables?

Tags: r, ggplot2, regression

I've created a variance-covariance matrix using `vcov()`. My sense is that `ggcorrplot` will visualize the matrix, but I can't make it work. I suspect it's because I've got *two* dependent variables, because all is fine when I do the same with a fit containing only one dependent variable. Where am I going wrong? Here is some data:

```
training_set_NORM <- data.frame(MD_EARN_WNE_P10 = c(.3094,.2901,.3401,.1311,.2022,.1301,.0872,.1412,.1184,.1296,.5555,.6666,.7777,.8888,.9999,.0204,.0305,.0406,.0507,.0608,.0709,.0214,.0315,.0416,.0517,.0618,.0719,.0325,.0426,.0527,.0628,.0729,.0591,.0692,.0793,.0894,.0995,,0022,.0033,.0044,.0055,.0066,.0077,.0088,.0099,.0908,.0907,.0906,.0905,.0904), ADM_RATE = c(.8177,.8189,.7979,.7734,.5744,.5273,.3197,.4319,.5107,.8827,.5655,.6766,.7677,.8688,.9699,.0204,.0305,.0406,.0507,.0608,.0709,.0214,.0315,.0416,.0517,.0618,.0719,.0325,.0426,.0527,.0628,.0729,.0591,.0692,.0793,.0894,.0995,,0022,.0033,.0044,.0055,.0066,.0077,.0088,.0099,.0908,.0907,.0906,.0905,.0904), UGDS = c(.1026,.4263,.3231,.024,.0116,.0886,.0281,.0141,.0276,.0721,.5755,.6566,.7877,.8788,.9799,.0204,.0305,.0406,.0507,.0608,.0709,.0214,.0315,.0416,.0517,.0618,.0719,.0325,.0426,.0527,.0628,.0729,.0591,.0692,.0793,.0894,.0995,,0022,.0033,.0044,.0055,.0066,.0077,.0088,.0099,.0908,.0907,.0906,.0905,.0904), SAT_AVG = c(.7097,.639,.6865,.4012,.4134,.4231,.3707,.5231,.4853,.5012,.9755,.6966,.7977,.8988,.9899,.0204,.0305,.0406,.0507,.0608,.0709,.0214,.0315,.0416,.0517,.0618,.0719,.0325,.0426,.0527,.0628,.0729,.0591,.0692,.0793,.0894,.0995,,0022,.0033,.0044,.0055,.0066,.0077,.0088,.0099,.0908,.0907,.0906,.0905,.0904), TUITIONFEE_OUT = c(.3776,.4907,.5054,.4428,.3325,.3199,.3833,.4315,.3221,.4132,.3755,.3966,.3977,.3988,.3899,.0204,.0305,.0406,.0507,.0608,.0709,.0214,.0315,.0416,.0517,.0618,.0719,.0325,.0426,.0527,.0628,.0729,.0591,.0692,.0793,.0894,.0995,,0022,.0033,.0044,.0055,.0066,.0077,.0088,.0099,.0908,.0907,.0906,.0905,.0904), AVGFACSAL = c(.361,.3951,.4204,.1525,.1908,.2242,.1797,.1068,.2517,.2845,.4755,.4966,.4977,.4988,.4899,.0204,.0305,.0406,.0507,.0608,.0709,.0214,.0315,.0416,.0517,.0618,.0719,.0325,.0426,.0527,.0628,.0729,.0591,.0692,.0793,.0894,.0995,,0022,.0033,.0044,.0055,.0066,.0077,.0088,.0099,.0908,.0907,.0906,.0905,.0904), PFTFAC = c(.6127,.7398,.8642,.4628,.4176,.6636,.42,1,.6779,1,.5745,.5946,.5973,.5985,.5895,.0204,.0305,.0406,.0507,.0608,.0709,.0214,.0315,.0416,.0517,.0618,.0719,.0325,.0426,.0527,.0628,.0729,.0591,.0692,.0793,.0894,.0995,,0022,.0033,.0044,.0055,.0066,.0077,.0088,.0099,.0908,.0907,.0906,.0905,.0904), RET_FT4_POOLED = c(.8077,.8615,.9,.5043,.5902,.7204,.5879,.7183,.7134,.7182,.9255,.2966,.2977,.2988,.2899,.0204,.0305,.0406,.0507,.0608,.0709,.0214,.0315,.0416,.0517,.0618,.0719,.0325,.0426,.0527,.0628,.0729,.0591,.0692,.0793,.0894,.0995,,0022,.0033,.0044,.0055,.0066,.0077,.0088,.0099,.0908,.0907,.0906,.0905,.0904), INEXPFTE = c(.0462,.0577,.0476,.0263,.0314,.0329,.0389,.0382,.0737,.0364,.17255,.1926,.1927,.1928,.1829,.0204,.0305,.0406,.0507,.0608,.0709,.0214,.0315,.0416,.0517,.0618,.0719,.0325,.0426,.0527,.0628,.0729,.0591,.0692,.0793,.0894,.0995,,0022,.0033,.0044,.0055,.0066,.0077,.0088,.0099,.0908,.0907,.0906,.0905,.0904), C100_4_POOLED = c(.2421,.5332,.5318,.1136,.3775,.1823,.1934,.3783,.3122,.2001,.2885,.2986,.2987,.2988,.1889,.0204,.0305,.0406,.0507,.0608,.0709,.0214,.0315,.0416,.0517,.0618,.0719,.0325,.0426,.0527,.0628,.0729,.0591,.0692,.0793,.0894,.0995,,0022,.0033,.0044,.0055,.0066,.0077,.0088,.0099,.0908,.0907,.0906,.0905,.0904), GRAD_DEBT_MDN = c(.537,.586,.538,.583,.704,.568,.674,.704,.608,.561,.0756,.0666,.0967,.0968,.0869,.0204,.0305,.0406,.0507,.0608,.0709,.0214,.0315,.0416,.0517,.0618,.0719,.0325,.0426,.0527,.0628,.0729,.0591,.0692,.0793,.0894,.0995,,0022,.0033,.0044,.0055,.0066,.0077,.0088,.0099,.0908,.0907,.0906,.0905,.0904), COSTT4_A = c(.2136,.2993,.324,.3632,.3994,.1429,.181,.389,.2255,.1699,.4745,.4466,.9447,.8944,.9494,.0204,.0305,.0406,.0507,.0608,.0709,.0214,.0315,.0416,.0517,.0618,.0719,.0325,.0426,.0527,.0628,.0729,.0591,.0692,.0793,.0894,.0995,,0022,.0033,.0044,.0055,.0066,.0077,.0088,.0099,.0908,.0907,.0906,.0905,.0904), X40.year.NPV = c(.3005,.2631,.3126,.1084,.1789,.1221,.0835,.1278,.1057,.1257,.9051,.6061,.7071,.8081,.0891,.0204,.0305,.0406,.0507,.0608,.0709,.0214,.0315,.0416,.0517,.0618,.0719,.0325,.0426,.0527,.0628,.0729,.0591,.0692,.0793,.0894,.0995,,0022,.0033,.0044,.0055,.0066,.0077,.0088,.0099,.0908,.0907,.0906,.0905,.0904)
```

And here's the model I'm using:

```
lm_joined1 <- lm(cbind(MD_EARN_WNE_P10, X40.year.NPV) ~ ADM_RATE + UGDS + SAT_AVG + TUITIONFEE_OUT + AVGFACSAL + PFTFAC + RET_FT4_POOLED + INEXPFTE + C100_4_POOLED, data = training_set_NORM)
```

I want to check covariance, so I use `vcov(lm_joined1)`, which yields a rather large output. So I want to visualize the matrix. Here's my attempt:

```
cor_matrix3 = vcov(lm_joined1, method='pearson',use='complete.obs')
head(cor_matrix3)
ggcorrplot(cor_matrix3, method = c("square"), type = c("full"), 
           ggtheme = ggplot2::theme_minimal, 
           title = "Correlation Matrix: Select Variables", show.legend = TRUE, 
           legend.title = "Corr", show.diag = FALSE, outline.color = "gray", 
           hc.order = TRUE, lab = TRUE, lab_col = "black", 
           lab_size = 2, tl.cex = 10, tl.col = "black", tl.srt = 45, digits = 2) + 
  theme(
   legend.key.width = unit(.6, "cm"),   #to resize legend
   legend.key.height = unit(1.4, "cm"),
  )
```

This does print a matrix with all variables, but every single box is `zero`:

[image]

**EDIT in response to comment**
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit 2: Try `lm` only with the significant variables from the full model. Also, with increasing observations, the covariance matrix does appear to get sparser. This may be because of the junk data you added or actually a phenomenon in your data, that there is no covariance structure...

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(ggcorrplot)
training_set_NORM <- data.frame(MD_EARN_WNE_P10 = c(.3094,.2901,.3401,.1311,.2022,.1301,.0872,.1412,.1184,.1296,.5555,.6666,.7777,.8888,.9999,.0204,.0305,.0406,.0507,.0608,.0709,.0214,.0315,.0416,.0517,.0618,.0719,.0325,.0426,.0527,.0628,.0729,.0591,.0692,.0793,.0894,.0995,0022,.0033,.0044,.0055,.0066,.0077,.0088,.0099,.0908,.0907,.0906,.0905,.0904), 
                                ADM_RATE = c(.8177,.8189,.7979,.7734,.5744,.5273,.3197,.4319,.5107,.8827,.5655,.6766,.7677,.8688,.9699,.0204,.0305,.0406,.0507,.0608,.0709,.0214,.0315,.0416,.0517,.0618,.0719,.0325,.0426,.0527,.0628,.0729,.0591,.0692,.0793,.0894,.0995,0022,.0033,.0044,.0055,.0066,.0077,.0088,.0099,.0908,.0907,.0906,.0905,.0904), 
                                UGDS = c(.1026,.4263,.3231,.024,.0116,.0886,.0281,.0141,.0276,.0721,.5755,.6566,.7877,.8788,.9799,.0204,.0305,.0406,.0507,.0608,.0709,.0214,.0315,.0416,.0517,.0618,.0719,.0325,.0426,.0527,.0628,.0729,.0591,.0692,.0793,.0894,.0995,0022,.0033,.0044,.0055,.0066,.0077,.0088,.0099,.0908,.0907,.0906,.0905,.0904), 
                                SAT_AVG = c(.7097,.639,.6865,.4012,.4134,.4231,.3707,.5231,.4853,.5012,.9755,.6966,.7977,.8988,.9899,.0204,.0305,.0406,.0507,.0608,.0709,.0214,.0315,.0416,.0517,.0618,.0719,.0325,.0426,.0527,.0628,.0729,.0591,.0692,.0793,.0894,.0995,0022,.0033,.0044,.0055,.0066,.0077,.0088,.0099,.0908,.0907,.0906,.0905,.0904), 
                                TUITIONFEE_OUT = c(.3776,.4907,.5054,.4428,.3325,.3199,.3833,.4315,.3221,.4132,.3755,.3966,.3977,.3988,.3899,.0204,.0305,.0406,.0507,.0608,.0709,.0214,.0315,.0416,.0517,.0618,.0719,.0325,.0426,.0527,.0628,.0729,.0591,.0692,.0793,.0894,.0995,0022,.0033,.0044,.0055,.0066,.0077,.0088,.0099,.0908,.0907,.0906,.0905,.0904), 
                                AVGFACSAL = c(.361,.3951,.4204,.1525,.1908,.2242,.1797,.1068,.2517,.2845,.4755,.4966,.4977,.4988,.4899,.0204,.0305,.0406,.0507,.0608,.0709,.0214,.0315,.0416,.0517,.0618,.0719,.0325,.0426,.0527,.0628,.0729,.0591,.0692,.0793,.0894,.0995,0022,.0033,.0044,.0055,.0066,.0077,.0088,.0099,.0908,.0907,.0906,.0905,.0904), 
                                PFTFAC = c(.6127,.7398,.8642,.4628,.4176,.6636,.42,1,.6779,1,.5745,.5946,.5973,.5985,.5895,.0204,.0305,.0406,.0507,.0608,.0709,.0214,.0315,.0416,.0517,.0618,.0719,.0325,.0426,.0527,.0628,.0729,.0591,.0692,.0793,.0894,.0995,0022,.0033,.0044,.0055,.0066,.0077,.0088,.0099,.0908,.0907,.0906,.0905,.0904), 
                                RET_FT4_POOLED = c(.8077,.8615,.9,.5043,.5902,.7204,.5879,.7183,.7134,.7182,.9255,.2966,.2977,.2988,.2899,.0204,.0305,.0406,.0507,.0608,.0709,.0214,.0315,.0416,.0517,.0618,.0719,.0325,.0426,.0527,.0628,.0729,.0591,.0692,.0793,.0894,.0995,0022,.0033,.0044,.0055,.0066,.0077,.0088,.0099,.0908,.0907,.0906,.0905,.0904), 
                                INEXPFTE = c(.0462,.0577,.0476,.0263,.0314,.0329,.0389,.0382,.0737,.0364,.17255,.1926,.1927,.1928,.1829,.0204,.0305,.0406,.0507,.0608,.0709,.0214,.0315,.0416,.0517,.0618,.0719,.0325,.0426,.0527,.0628,.0729,.0591,.0692,.0793,.0894,.0995,0022,.0033,.0044,.0055,.0066,.0077,.0088,.0099,.0908,.0907,.0906,.0905,.0904), 
                                C100_4_POOLED = c(.2421,.5332,.5318,.1136,.3775,.1823,.1934,.3783,.3122,.2001,.2885,.2986,.2987,.2988,.1889,.0204,.0305,.0406,.0507,.0608,.0709,.0214,.0315,.0416,.0517,.0618,.0719,.0325,.0426,.0527,.0628,.0729,.0591,.0692,.0793,.0894,.0995,0022,.0033,.0044,.0055,.0066,.0077,.0088,.0099,.0908,.0907,.0906,.0905,.0904), 
                                GRAD_DEBT_MDN = c(.537,.586,.538,.583,.704,.568,.674,.704,.608,.561,.0756,.0666,.0967,.0968,.0869,.0204,.0305,.0406,.0507,.0608,.0709,.0214,.0315,.0416,.0517,.0618,.0719,.0325,.0426,.0527,.0628,.0729,.0591,.0692,.0793,.0894,.0995,0022,.0033,.0044,.0055,.0066,.0077,.0088,.0099,.0908,.0907,.0906,.0905,.0904), 
                                COSTT4_A = c(.2136,.2993,.324,.3632,.3994,.1429,.181,.389,.2255,.1699,.4745,.4466,.9447,.8944,.9494,.0204,.0305,.0406,.0507,.0608,.0709,.0214,.0315,.0416,.0517,.0618,.0719,.0325,.0426,.0527,.0628,.0729,.0591,.0692,.0793,.0894,.0995,0022,.0033,.0044,.0055,.0066,.0077,.0088,.0099,.0908,.0907,.0906,.0905,.0904), 
                                X40.year.NPV = c(.3005,.2631,.3126,.1084,.1789,.1221,.0835,.1278,.1057,.1257,.9051,.6061,.7071,.8081,.0891,.0204,.0305,.0406,.0507,.0608,.0709,.0214,.0315,.0416,.0517,.0618,.0719,.0325,.0426,.0527,.0628,.0729,.0591,.0692,.0793,.0894,.0995,0022,.0033,.0044,.0055,.0066,.0077,.0088,.0099,.0908,.0907,.0906,.0905,.0904))

nrow(training_set_NORM)
#> [1] 50

lm_joined2 <- lm(cbind(MD_EARN_WNE_P10, X40.year.NPV) ~  UGDS + SAT_AVG + TUITIONFEE_OUT + AVGFACSAL + RET_FT4_POOLED, 
                 data = training_set_NORM)
cor_matrix3 = vcov(lm_joined2, complete = TRUE, method='pearson',use='complete.obs')
# head(cor_matrix3)
ggcorrplot::ggcorrplot(cor_matrix3, method = c("square"), type = c("full"), 
           ggtheme = ggplot2::theme_minimal, 
           title = "Correlation Matrix: Select Variables", show.legend = TRUE, 
           legend.title = "Corr", show.diag = FALSE, outline.color = "gray", 
           hc.order = TRUE, lab = TRUE, lab_col = "black", 
           lab_size = 2, tl.cex = 10, tl.col = "black", tl.srt = 45, digits = 2) + 
  theme(
    legend.key.width = unit(.6, "cm"),   #to resize legend
    legend.key.height = unit(1.4, "cm"),
  )
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-04-15 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Edit: this still works for 50 obs (your data has some extra commas, so copy mine and replace yours).

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(ggcorrplot)
training_set_NORM <- data.frame(MD_EARN_WNE_P10 = c(.3094,.2901,.3401,.1311,.2022,.1301,.0872,.1412,.1184,.1296,.5555,.6666,.7777,.8888,.9999,.0204,.0305,.0406,.0507,.0608,.0709,.0214,.0315,.0416,.0517,.0618,.0719,.0325,.0426,.0527,.0628,.0729,.0591,.0692,.0793,.0894,.0995,0022,.0033,.0044,.0055,.0066,.0077,.0088,.0099,.0908,.0907,.0906,.0905,.0904), 
                                ADM_RATE = c(.8177,.8189,.7979,.7734,.5744,.5273,.3197,.4319,.5107,.8827,.5655,.6766,.7677,.8688,.9699,.0204,.0305,.0406,.0507,.0608,.0709,.0214,.0315,.0416,.0517,.0618,.0719,.0325,.0426,.0527,.0628,.0729,.0591,.0692,.0793,.0894,.0995,0022,.0033,.0044,.0055,.0066,.0077,.0088,.0099,.0908,.0907,.0906,.0905,.0904), 
                                UGDS = c(.1026,.4263,.3231,.024,.0116,.0886,.0281,.0141,.0276,.0721,.5755,.6566,.7877,.8788,.9799,.0204,.0305,.0406,.0507,.0608,.0709,.0214,.0315,.0416,.0517,.0618,.0719,.0325,.0426,.0527,.0628,.0729,.0591,.0692,.0793,.0894,.0995,0022,.0033,.0044,.0055,.0066,.0077,.0088,.0099,.0908,.0907,.0906,.0905,.0904), 
                                SAT_AVG = c(.7097,.639,.6865,.4012,.4134,.4231,.3707,.5231,.4853,.5012,.9755,.6966,.7977,.8988,.9899,.0204,.0305,.0406,.0507,.0608,.0709,.0214,.0315,.0416,.0517,.0618,.0719,.0325,.0426,.0527,.0628,.0729,.0591,.0692,.0793,.0894,.0995,0022,.0033,.0044,.0055,.0066,.0077,.0088,.0099,.0908,.0907,.0906,.0905,.0904), 
                                TUITIONFEE_OUT = c(.3776,.4907,.5054,.4428,.3325,.3199,.3833,.4315,.3221,.4132,.3755,.3966,.3977,.3988,.3899,.0204,.0305,.0406,.0507,.0608,.0709,.0214,.0315,.0416,.0517,.0618,.0719,.0325,.0426,.0527,.0628,.0729,.0591,.0692,.0793,.0894,.0995,0022,.0033,.0044,.0055,.0066,.0077,.0088,.0099,.0908,.0907,.0906,.0905,.0904), 
                                AVGFACSAL = c(.361,.3951,.4204,.1525,.1908,.2242,.1797,.1068,.2517,.2845,.4755,.4966,.4977,.4988,.4899,.0204,.0305,.0406,.0507,.0608,.0709,.0214,.0315,.0416,.0517,.0618,.0719,.0325,.0426,.0527,.0628,.0729,.0591,.0692,.0793,.0894,.0995,0022,.0033,.0044,.0055,.0066,.0077,.0088,.0099,.0908,.0907,.0906,.0905,.0904), 
                                PFTFAC = c(.6127,.7398,.8642,.4628,.4176,.6636,.42,1,.6779,1,.5745,.5946,.5973,.5985,.5895,.0204,.0305,.0406,.0507,.0608,.0709,.0214,.0315,.0416,.0517,.0618,.0719,.0325,.0426,.0527,.0628,.0729,.0591,.0692,.0793,.0894,.0995,0022,.0033,.0044,.0055,.0066,.0077,.0088,.0099,.0908,.0907,.0906,.0905,.0904), 
                                RET_FT4_POOLED = c(.8077,.8615,.9,.5043,.5902,.7204,.5879,.7183,.7134,.7182,.9255,.2966,.2977,.2988,.2899,.0204,.0305,.0406,.0507,.0608,.0709,.0214,.0315,.0416,.0517,.0618,.0719,.0325,.0426,.0527,.0628,.0729,.0591,.0692,.0793,.0894,.0995,0022,.0033,.0044,.0055,.0066,.0077,.0088,.0099,.0908,.0907,.0906,.0905,.0904), 
                                INEXPFTE = c(.0462,.0577,.0476,.0263,.0314,.0329,.0389,.0382,.0737,.0364,.17255,.1926,.1927,.1928,.1829,.0204,.0305,.0406,.0507,.0608,.0709,.0214,.0315,.0416,.0517,.0618,.0719,.0325,.0426,.0527,.0628,.0729,.0591,.0692,.0793,.0894,.0995,0022,.0033,.0044,.0055,.0066,.0077,.0088,.0099,.0908,.0907,.0906,.0905,.0904), 
                                C100_4_POOLED = c(.2421,.5332,.5318,.1136,.3775,.1823,.1934,.3783,.3122,.2001,.2885,.2986,.2987,.2988,.1889,.0204,.0305,.0406,.0507,.0608,.0709,.0214,.0315,.0416,.0517,.0618,.0719,.0325,.0426,.0527,.0628,.0729,.0591,.0692,.0793,.0894,.0995,0022,.0033,.0044,.0055,.0066,.0077,.0088,.0099,.0908,.0907,.0906,.0905,.0904), 
                                GRAD_DEBT_MDN = c(.537,.586,.538,.583,.704,.568,.674,.704,.608,.561,.0756,.0666,.0967,.0968,.0869,.0204,.0305,.0406,.0507,.0608,.0709,.0214,.0315,.0416,.0517,.0618,.0719,.0325,.0426,.0527,.0628,.0729,.0591,.0692,.0793,.0894,.0995,0022,.0033,.0044,.0055,.0066,.0077,.0088,.0099,.0908,.0907,.0906,.0905,.0904), 
                                COSTT4_A = c(.2136,.2993,.324,.3632,.3994,.1429,.181,.389,.2255,.1699,.4745,.4466,.9447,.8944,.9494,.0204,.0305,.0406,.0507,.0608,.0709,.0214,.0315,.0416,.0517,.0618,.0719,.0325,.0426,.0527,.0628,.0729,.0591,.0692,.0793,.0894,.0995,0022,.0033,.0044,.0055,.0066,.0077,.0088,.0099,.0908,.0907,.0906,.0905,.0904), 
                                X40.year.NPV = c(.3005,.2631,.3126,.1084,.1789,.1221,.0835,.1278,.1057,.1257,.9051,.6061,.7071,.8081,.0891,.0204,.0305,.0406,.0507,.0608,.0709,.0214,.0315,.0416,.0517,.0618,.0719,.0325,.0426,.0527,.0628,.0729,.0591,.0692,.0793,.0894,.0995,0022,.0033,.0044,.0055,.0066,.0077,.0088,.0099,.0908,.0907,.0906,.0905,.0904))

nrow(training_set_NORM)
#> [1] 50

lm_joined1 <- lm(cbind(MD_EARN_WNE_P10, X40.year.NPV) ~ ADM_RATE + UGDS + SAT_AVG + TUITIONFEE_OUT + AVGFACSAL + PFTFAC + RET_FT4_POOLED + INEXPFTE + C100_4_POOLED, 
                 data = training_set_NORM)
cor_matrix3 = vcov(lm_joined1, complete = TRUE, method='pearson',use='complete.obs')
# head(cor_matrix3)
ggcorrplot::ggcorrplot(cor_matrix3, method = c("square"), type = c("full"), 
           ggtheme = ggplot2::theme_minimal, 
           title = "Correlation Matrix: Select Variables", show.legend = TRUE, 
           legend.title = "Corr", show.diag = FALSE, outline.color = "gray", 
           hc.order = TRUE, lab = TRUE, lab_col = "black", 
           lab_size = 2, tl.cex = 10, tl.col = "black", tl.srt = 45, digits = 2) + 
  theme(
    legend.key.width = unit(.6, "cm"),   #to resize legend
    legend.key.height = unit(1.4, "cm"),
  )
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-04-15 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

This works for me for 15 obs:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(ggcorrplot)
training_set_NORM <- data.frame(MD_EARN_WNE_P10 = c(.3094,.2901,.3401,.1311,.2022,.1301,.0872,.1412,.1184,.1296,.5555,.6666,.7777,.8888,.9999), ADM_RATE = c(.8177,.8189,.7979,.7734,.5744,.5273,.3197,.4319,.5107,.8827,.5655,.6766,.7677,.8688,.9699), UGDS = c(.1026,.4263,.3231,.024,.0116,.0886,.0281,.0141,.0276,.0721,.5755,.6566,.7877,.8788,.9799), SAT_AVG = c(.7097,.639,.6865,.4012,.4134,.4231,.3707,.5231,.4853,.5012,.9755,.6966,.7977,.8988,.9899), TUITIONFEE_OUT = c(.3776,.4907,.5054,.4428,.3325,.3199,.3833,.4315,.3221,.4132,.3755,.3966,.3977,.3988,.3899), AVGFACSAL = c(.361,.3951,.4204,.1525,.1908,.2242,.1797,.1068,.2517,.2845,.4755,.4966,.4977,.4988,.4899), PFTFAC = c(.6127,.7398,.8642,.4628,.4176,.6636,.42,1,.6779,1,.5745,.5946,.5973,.5985,.5895), RET_FT4_POOLED = c(.8077,.8615,.9,.5043,.5902,.7204,.5879,.7183,.7134,.7182,.9255,.2966,.2977,.2988,.2899), INEXPFTE = c(.0462,.0577,.0476,.0263,.0314,.0329,.0389,.0382,.0737,.0364,.17255,.1926,.1927,.1928,.1829), C100_4_POOLED = c(.2421,.5332,.5318,.1136,.3775,.1823,.1934,.3783,.3122,.2001,.2885,.2986,.2987,.2988,.1889), GRAD_DEBT_MDN = c(.537,.586,.538,.583,.704,.568,.674,.704,.608,.561,.0756,.0666,.0967,.0968,.0869), COSTT4_A = c(.2136,.2993,.324,.3632,.3994,.1429,.181,.389,.2255,.1699,.4745,.4466,.9447,.8944,.9494), X40.year.NPV = c(.3005,.2631,.3126,.1084,.1789,.1221,.0835,.1278,.1057,.1257,.9051,.6061,.7071,.8081,.0891))
nrow(training_set_NORM)
#> [1] 15

lm_joined1 <- lm(cbind(MD_EARN_WNE_P10, X40.year.NPV) ~ ADM_RATE + UGDS + SAT_AVG + TUITIONFEE_OUT + AVGFACSAL + PFTFAC + RET_FT4_POOLED + INEXPFTE + C100_4_POOLED, 
                 data = training_set_NORM)
cor_matrix3 = vcov(lm_joined1, complete = TRUE, method='pearson',use='complete.obs')
# head(cor_matrix3)
ggcorrplot::ggcorrplot(cor_matrix3, method = c("square"), type = c("full"), 
           ggtheme = ggplot2::theme_minimal, 
           title = "Correlation Matrix: Select Variables", show.legend = TRUE, 
           legend.title = "Corr", show.diag = FALSE, outline.color = "gray", 
           hc.order = TRUE, lab = TRUE, lab_col = "black", 
           lab_size = 2, tl.cex = 10, tl.col = "black", tl.srt = 45, digits = 2) + 
  theme(
    legend.key.width = unit(.6, "cm"),   #to resize legend
    legend.key.height = unit(1.4, "cm"),
  )
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-04-15 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: You must've been pointing that out as I was making the edit, @Nick Camarda. Caught it shortly after posting. To be clear: my problem/question remains. Thanks!

Comment: Just to be clear, you also get NaN's when you call `vcov(lm_joined1)` - this is your question, why are you getting NaN's with this call?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: I've added to OP

Comment: @RKeithL are you sharing all of the data with us? Only 10 observations for an 11 parameter model is why we can't reproduce your issue

Comment: my full data set (`training_set_NORM `) training contains over 1,100 observations. Here--I'll edit OP to add in a few additional lines

Comment: Yes no need to add the full dataset, at least 50 observations would be nice

Comment: I've added a bunch of junk lines to beef it up to 50 lines. Thanks for your help on this, btw.

Comment: Well, I guess my original plat *does* work and all O's is correct...although I do not understand *why* that would be the case. Correlation matrices for the dependent variables taken separately each show correlation. Regardless, thank you, @Nick Camarda, for your helpfulness. Much appreciated.

Comment: @RKeithL no problem! I'm sorry I cannot further help with the "why" question - perhaps Math Stackexchange or Cross Validated may help for more discussion?